# Time outs when copying files across the network, Linux to Linux

Tags: linux-mint, network-shares

I want to copy some files (700mb-2gb) across the network to my other machine. Both are running Linux Mint. Some files work, sometimes I have to retry 4-5 times. Is there some type of timing change I can make to prevent this? I am using the gui interface which comes with Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon and trying both copy and paste or trying cut and paste. Thanks